# Set the primary keyboard language

Tags: windows, keyboard, language

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but how do I set the primary language to my keyboard, while keeping the rest of windows in English? Because im tired of switching to my keyboard language every time I login.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10, do this :

- Run *Settings > Time & Language > Language*
- Under "Preferred languages" you will see your installed keyboards
- Drag and drop your preferred keyboard so it's the first in the list
- It will now be the default keyboard after boot.